# undefined index for postimg and postid array's

Tags: php, arrays, image, undefined-index

Here's my code, I have undefined index notices on the second to last line where I define the $params variable. Here is my call to uploadImage where I pass $params value from another file,

```
Image::uploadImage('postimg', "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg = :postimg WHERE id = :postid", array(':postid' => $postid),array(':postimg' => $postimg));
```

I've tried checking if postimg and postid is set and if they were empty, but nothing in those if statements were being executed.

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

    class Image
    {
        public static function uploadImage($formname,$query,$params)
        {
            $image = "";

            $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES[$formname]['tmp_name']));

            $options = array('http'=>array(
                'method'=>"POST",
                'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer access code here\n".
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'content'=>$image
            ));

            $context = stream_context_create($options);
            $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
            if ($_FILES[$formname]['size'] > 10240000) {
                die('Image too big, must be 10MB or less!');
            }
                  $curl_handle=curl_init();
                  curl_setopt($curl_handle,       CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.imgur.com/3/image&mpaction=convert format=flv');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'beautify');
$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

                echo 'hell0';

            $response = json_decode($response);
            $params = array(':postid' => $params['postid'], ':postimg' => $params['postimg']);
            connect::query($query,$params);


        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: You have __4__ arguments in a function call, but only __3__ in a function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closer at `Image::uploadImage` call:

```
Image::uploadImage(
    // $formname argument
    'postimg', 
    // $query argument 
    "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg = :postimg WHERE id = :postid",  
    // $params argument
    array(':postid' => $postid),
    // Wait what is this?
    array(':postimg' => $postimg)
);
```

So, your params should be passed as **one** array:

```
Image::uploadImage(
    // $formname argument
    'postimg', 
    // $query argument 
    "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg = :postimg WHERE id = :postid",  
    // $params argument
    array(
        ':postid' => $postid,
        ':postimg' => $postimg
    )
);
```

Next, you don't have `'postid'` key in `$params`. You have `':postid'`.

So, either line

```
$params = array(':postid' => $params['postid'], ':postimg' => $params['postimg']);
```

must be:

```
// add ':' prefix
$params = array(':postid' => $params[':postid'], ':postimg' => $params[':postimg']);
```

Or, argument passed to function should be:

```
// $params argument, no `:` prefixes
array(
    'postid' => $postid,
    'postimg' => $postimg
)
```

Comment: thanks man but now I get this notice, Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: should I convert it myself?

Comment: This means that somewhere you try to print value which is array.